Java jackson deserilization for child classes
I have follow class structure.
class Evaluator {}
class ChildEvaluator1 : extends Evaluator
class ChildEvaluator2 : extends Evaluator

and I have following JSON structure.
{
   "evaluator":{
      "_class":"ChildEvaluator1",
      "type":"ChildEvaluator1",
      "operator":"greater_than_equal"
   }
}

and I'm using Objectmapper to de-serialize it.
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
   mapper.registerSubtypes(new NamedType(ChildEvaluator1.class, "ChildEvaluator1"));

but I'm always getting back instance of Evaluator instead of ChildEvaluator1, what I'm doing wrong?

Did you try to cast the result to the ChildEvaluator1?
